# CFG : Every rule in a context-free grammar is of the form: A->B, What do A and B represent?

Tags: machine-learning

I came up with the quiz question in my syllabus. Can somebody help me with this with explanation?

Every rule in a context-free grammar is of the form: A->B, What do A and B represent?

Ans Option:
1. A is either a POS Tag or a Terminal symbol; B is a POS Tag or Non-terminal symbol
2. A is a Non-terminal symbol or a POS tag; B is either a POS Tag or a Terminal symbol
3. Both A and B are Terminal symbols
4. A and B can either be POS Tag or a Terminal symbol

Answer (score 0):

A is non-terminal/ POS tag. B is POS or a Terminal symbol